# Convert big varbinary field to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the table, that contains only two fields:

```
[HelpFileName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[HelpFileData] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL
```

That table stores different help files. There is one file which size is 4 858 640 bytes or 4,63 Mb. And all its data stored in [HelpFileData] field.
I want to convert that data from varbinary to string and do it in this way:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),  [HelpFileData], 1)
```

This code works, but gives me a truncated string. 
How can I do it without truncation?

Comment: how do you know the string is truncated?

Comment: And what good is converting it to a varchar anyway?

Comment: FILESTREAM may be a better option.

Comment: @vkp it is simple. I show here only part of my code, but in my project I add another text to this string. The problem was detected when I try to do it with this big file data, but when there was a little files my resulting string was complete

Comment: @brightside90, Why would you want to convert varbinary to NVARCHAR, Just curious more than anything

Comment: @GouriShankarAechoor just an experiment. If you know better method I will be very grateful

Comment: Yes, in my opinion FILESTREAM may be a better option. It moves a way the responsibility of managing the files to NTFS which for me is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Management Studio` to display the result, you will probably see a truncated string.

Comment: Not entirely true @serge, Its only true for message pain not if the result is retrieved using a select or even export.

Comment: No I don't use only Management Studio, but I know that it can do such thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to use varchar(max) with style as 0

```
create table tvarbin (
[HelpFileName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[HelpFileData] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL
)

insert into tvarbin(HelpFileName,HelpFileData) values 
('testfile',convert(varbinary(max), '...your 8000+content'))

select *, convert(varchar(max),helpfiledata, 0) from tvarbin
```

Comment: The result string in this case contains only chineese or japanese symbols (actually, I can't distinguish them).